# Automatic generation of a powerpoint presentation from a checkbox menu

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, office-2013

I would like to create a file in which the user will access to a checkbox list of Powerpoint files select the one he needs, and execute a macro(?) that will generate automatically a Powerpoint presentation merging the selected presentations.

I don't need any code or anything like that, I just don't really know which solution would be better.
I am quite sur that I can do it with a excel and a macro, there might be 100% Powerpoint solution, I could code that with some php/js (maybe?), but that might not be de easiest solution, so I would like to know how you guys would proceed to create that kind of Powerpoint generating app ?

I'm not sure to be clear so don't hesitate to ask me for details.

Thank you in advance for your advices.

Ploggy.

Comment: Unless Excel is providing some data, there's no point in adding it to the mix. Likewise, php or javascript aren't especially helpful. Just use plain old VBA to present a userform with the PowerPoint choices on it, then run a macro to do whatever final processing is required.

Comment: Hello @JohnKorchok, Thank you for your  answer. I'll go for a VBA / PPT then. Thank's again for you help.